# xfsrestore: unexpected tape error

Tags: xfs

I'm trying to test tape backup of a specific directory, made using:

```
xfsdump -l 0 -f /dev/nst0 -L "session label" -M "media label" -s mybackups /NFSMOUNT
```

Checking the dump contents succeeds without errors:

```
xfsrestore -f /dev/nst0 -t
```

But when to restore the dump, I get:

```
xfsrestore -f /dev/nst0 -i .
xfsrestore: ERROR: unexpected tape error: errno 16 nread -1 blksz 1048576 recsz 1048576 isvar 1 wasatbot 1 eod 0 fmk 0 eot 0 onl 1 1 wprot 0 ew 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Is anything else using the tape device? `errno 16` is `EBUSY`, defined as *Device or resource busy*

A silly question, but I assume you rewound the tape after the test? A tape device that has a name starting with **n** is not auto-rewinding (ie, unless you rewound it, after testing your backup the tape will be positioned after your backup).

You can use the following to rewind it:

```
mt -f /dev/st0 rewind
```

Comment: No. Nothing else is using it. Yes, I  rewound it after creating the dump. Strangely, xfsrestore works in non interactive mode. Perhaps interactive restore is unavailable for subdirectory dumps.